# How to convert the function key F3 to a byte array?

Tags: c#

How to convert the function key F3 to a byte array in C#? We tried the below code, but it has't worked.

```
Secondcommand = "\x1bOR"; //F3
byte[] Bcommand_sec3 = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Secondcommand);
Obj_StreamOutput.Write(Bcommand_sec3, 0,Bcommand_sec3.Length);
```

Answer (score 0):

try following

```
public static byte[] StrToByteArray(string hexValue) {
    return Enumerable.Range(0, hexValue.Length)
                 .Where(x => x % 2 == 0)
                 .Select(x => Convert.ToByte(hexValue.Substring(x, 2), 16))
                 .ToArray();
}
```

Comment: for function key F3, what string we have to use?

Comment: I tried passing this  "0x0172" (F3) hexa decimal value to the above function but i got below error...
 Error While Executing the SUDO SU COMMAND Erroe Message is  Could not find any recognizable digits.